# Exceptions to Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, joomla, permalinks

My client's previous outsourcing firm managed to get all of his Joomla websites hacked, and I'm moving all of them over to wordpress and cleaning things up. In the process, I'd like to preserve his SEO, so what I'm trying to do is to make the permalinks to blogposts look like those in joomla.

To do this, I changed my permalinks to /index.php/blog/%postname%/

This actually worked!

**but, now the problem**

I have a folder called images in the root of the website. These were the previous images from joomla, and it's a lot easier for me to just link to it there than to upload all of them via wordpress.

However, after changing my permalinks, if I try to visit http://[root_url]/images, the permalinks act up and won't let me link to the images.

My question is, how would I like to an image in the /images folder of root, knowing that my permalinks are set as -- > /index.php/blog/%postname%/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, sorry for the dumb question. It seems like I didn't actually have the folder properly structured.

If the folder actually was in root, it would work.